# PHP - Get the id of the table row clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating the account management system of my website and I decided to add a feature that enables me to declare weather a specific account is active or inactive. The data is retrieved from my mysql table.

```
$query = mysqli_query($DBConnect,"SELECT * from REG");
echo "<table class = 'table'  style = 'width:90%;text-align:center'>";
        while($getData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $username = $getData['uname'];
            $fname = $getData['fname'];
            $mname = $getData['mname'];
            $lname = $getData['lname'];
            $bday = $getData['bday'];
            $email = $getData['email'];
            $contact = $getData['contact'];
            $gender = $getData['gender'];
            if($getData['userlevel'] == 1)
            {
                $userlevel = "user";
            }
            else
            {
                $userlevel = "admin";
            }
            if($getData['status'] == 1)
            {
                $status = "active";
            }
            else
            {
                $status = "disabled";
            }

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$username</td><td>$fname</td><td>$mname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$bday</td><td>$email</td><td>$contact</td><td>$gender</td><td>$userlevel</td><td>
            <a href ='..\status.php' >$status </a></td></tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
```

This is the content of status.php

```
session_start();
$DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","kenginakalbo")
or die ("Unable to connect".mysqli_error());


$query = mysqli_query($DBConnect,"SELECT * from REG where id = '$_SESSION[id]'");
        while($getData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $status = $getData['status'];
            echo "'$_SESSION[id]'";
        }

if($status == 1)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($DBConnect, "UPDATE REG SET status = 0 where id = '$_SESSION[id]'");
}
else if ($status == 0)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($DBConnect, "UPDATE REG SET status = 1 where id = '$_SESSION[id]'");
}

header("Location: admin/login.php");
```

What I need to do is get the ID of the row clicked and declare it in my session so that it can be used in the "status.php" file. But in this code, the last id in the table is the one that is declared into the session because of the loop. How do I get the value of the id of the row that is clicked? (is there sort of like onClick function in php? Thank you.

Comment: You should read about $_GET global variable. You can pass in url parametr for example id like this status.php?id=$id, and then in status.php get that variable $id = $_GET['id']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass id parameter,

```
status.php?id=$id;
```

in `status.php`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: This is new to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
   echo "<td>$username</td><td>$fname</td><td>$mname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$bday</td><td>$email</td><td>$contact</td><td>$gender</td><td>$userlevel</td><td>
    <a href ='..\status.php' >$status </a></td></tr>";
```

to:

```
   echo "<td>$username</td><td>$fname</td><td>$mname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$bday</td><td>$email</td><td>$contact</td><td>$gender</td><td>$userlevel</td><td>
    <a href ='..\status.php{$getData['id']}' >$status </a></td></tr>";
```

And in your status.php change `$_SESSION['id']` to `$_GET['id']`. But make sure to first prevent SQL injection either through `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])` or through PDO.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no onclick function in PHP but you can create a form with a button on each row that holds the value of the row that it is in. Have that form simply do a post or a get request back to the status.php. Adding it to the session might be a bad idea.

Instead of a button you can also create a link modify your loop so that there is a property called $rowid and increment it within your loop.

```
<a href="/status.php?rowid=<?php echo $rowid; ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, what you really want is to use a GET superglobal here. You can switch

for

Then, you use $_GET["userid"] instead of $_SESSION[id] on the status.php page.

Also, you dont need a while for the status page. You should check the number of results, if it was 1 it means the user exists, and then you just do a $getData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) without the while